# New users can't create an account with part of an already existing username (text file problem)

Tags: python, text-files, account

I'm relatively new to python and am trying to create a reliable account creation and storage program. When the user wants to create a new username, the username_storage file is read to see if it already exists for another account.

```
# Enter and check username
            new_user = input("Username: ")
            if new_user in username_storage:
                print("Sorry, that username is already taken.\n")
            else:
                break
```

The problem is that whenever the user tries to create a new account using part of an existing username, the program does not allow it because it registers that the new username is inside a pre-made username.

e.g. if "william" is an existing username in the username_storage text file, it doesn't allow the new username "will" or "liam" because those names are inside "william".

Thanks to anyone who may be able to answer this question; if I haven't explained my problem clearly enough, please let me know!

Comment: In the beginning of the program read all usernames to a list and check the username in that list or not

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to make a [mre], which means enough code to reproduce the problem as well as expected output and actual output. BTW, if you want more tips, check out [ask].

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
usernames = username_storage.split()
print(new_user in usernames)
```

would do what you want assuming you cant have spaces in the username

Comment: Why do you assume usernames are separated by whitespace? They might be CSV.

Comment: Why do you assume usernames can't contain whitespace?

Comment: Why do you assume `username_storage` is a string? OP said it's a file. They may be wrong though, since `new_user` can't contain a newline and `in <file>` checks against lines.

Comment: your right it looks like it could be a file and that might work ...  i assumed `string in filehandle` would fail but a quick test showed me i was wrong